# Migrating from Weblogic to Spring/HikariCP

Tags: spring, db2, weblogic, datasource, hikaricp

My current system is as follows:

- Weblogic 12c
- Spring 3.x
- JSF 1.1

We are looking to migrate from Weblogic to HikariCP as we start our transition to Spring Boot & Angular.

Our datasources were setup and maintained in Weblogic and configured in Spring via the JndiObjectFactoryBean.

We'd like to lift our weblogic datasource/connection pool and replace it with Spring/Hikari.

I've changed all of the dataSources to Spring JDBC Beans.

Without changing my code is there a way to setup Hikari with these Datasource changes?

```
<bean id = "dataSource"
            class = 
  "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name = "driverClassName" value = 
      "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"/>
   <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:as400://test"/>
   <property name = "username" value = "xxxxx"/>
   <property name = "password" value = "xxxxx"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What you mean by "without changing the code"? at least you have to change the data-source related beans.

Comment: Yes, I'm fine with changing the Data-Source and Bean information in my properties.  I just wanted to make sure I didn't have to change my jdbc and perpared statements within my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in context file will be :

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" />
            <property name="minimumIdle" value="1"/>
            <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10"/>
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="5000"/>
            <property name="dataSourceProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="url">jdbc:as400://test</prop>
                    <prop key="user">xxxxx</prop>
                    <prop key="password">xxxxx</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
 </bean>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks Anish.  I'll try this later today!